# chrome extension ask the user to sign in when installing it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following chrome extension manifest file

```
    {
  "short_name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "name": "test Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "test Extension",
    "default_icon": {
      "48": "assets/icon-32.png",
      "128": "assets/icon-32.png"
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://mail.google.com/*",
        "http://mail.google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "gmail_contentScripts.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "content_style.css"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://drive.google.com/*",
        "http://drive.google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "drive_contentScript.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "content_style.css"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://docs.google.com/*",
        "http://docs.google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "docs_contentScript.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "content_style.css"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://calendar.google.com/*",
        "http://calendar.google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "calendar_contentScript.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "content_style.css"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "assets/icon-32.png",
    "128": "assets/icon-32.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "scripting",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "contextMenus",
    "identity",
    "webNavigation",
    "system.display"
    
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "*.png"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    },
    {
      "resources": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    },
    {
      "resources": [
        "*.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    },
    {
      "resources": [
        "*.css"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    },
    {
      "resources": [
        "*.svg"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "768976677270-higgtvslsjcamcqurr6fhdsmvt5a4ggs.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
    ]
  },
  "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAp7ld8Mr659Cqn9FV5cgDsQLVqsEEN/KBJH1dDuOHROhevUPgBHbDRbWqvc5bvc0PyULVAE5+dRlie0oUZ26tz5P6Ha6kk+XXRbcedP2ltJhXDEZyyBaYSrEwyKI3NEwadElStwLFITLkUNfeM2RO4nG1++6Jvt6XM8HgfUYxpO4deOGG2zePPHxciIi18DlDbMQSGUKIONWvmDWNsSu1We9KfdKTp3wb9mAO22jDhCGQQ5axLvQdkGjfMGmrOFte8fvDy+XmUlLQmBGzjwHmVj43sLEjoTUaSrkVv1jfiBwI9s6pbu0BCQJHB/vlKrf9FWx7LRp7BINwjSRriuhVrwIDAQAB"
}
```

when I install the application for the first time and try to use it it will automatically redirect me to gmail to sign in with my account does the `oauth2.0` responsible for that?

As i am using the oauth2.0 to access google api in some cases ( when the user is signed in to gmail for example, using the `gmail_contentscript.js`, is there a way to prevent the redirection to gmail only if the user is inside gmail website itself?

In other words is there a way to let the user use my extension even if he is not signed in as i want it to be like so